# How can i form the property in compose to return int(0) if condition is true and not return anything if condition is false?

Tags: expression, azure-logic-apps

How can i form this expression to return int value of 0 if true and don't return the property if false? warehouse event is an array and the property is inside a compose.

Expression:

> if(contains(variables('WareHouseEvent'), 'OB_2910'), int(0), <not
> return anything)

[image: See property here]

Comment: So you don’t want to return the property at all, meaning it doesn’t exist in the object if it falls into the false condition?

Comment: That's right, if warehouse order doesn't contain OB_2910 i dont want to return the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to the first answer is to always add and then remove it after the fact.

[image: Flow]

This is an example you can copy into your own tenant for testing.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose_JSON_Object": {
                "inputs": {
                    "AnotherProperty": "Another Value",
                    "TestProperty": "@variables('Data')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Integer": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_Integer": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Data",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "New_JSON_Object": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "New Object",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": "@if(equals(variables('Data'), 1), removeProperty(outputs('Compose_JSON_Object'), 'TestProperty'), outputs('Compose_JSON_Object'))"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_JSON_Object": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "conditions": [],
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

I have an integer variable at the top which stores a value of either 1 or 0.

[image: Variable]

Then in my compose, I add that value to a property in the compose statement.

[image: Compose]

Then beneath that, I set a new variable with the (potentially) updated object using an expression to determine if the added property should be removed or not.

**You'd just need to adjust the condition portion of the IF statement with your expression.**

```
if(equals(variables('Data'), 1), removeProperty(outputs('Compose_JSON_Object'), 'TestProperty'), outputs('Compose_JSON_Object'))
```

The property will be removed depending on the value of the `Data` variable.

##### Removed

[image: Removed]

##### Retained

[image: Retained]

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is that you can use `Condition` connector when if the mentioned condition satisfies it executes true block else it executes false. From there you can use the same Compose content.

Here is the screenshot of the logic app  -

[image]

output :-

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you guys both of your answers is a solution to my problem, I appreciate it :)